# Switch view controller depending on bool value

Tags: ios, swift

I have a load page in my application I created. I am trying to set up a tutorial. The load page will simple switch view controllers depending if the tutorial has been completed or not.

I would like to have the app perform the tutorial once when it is opened for the first time. I have created two segue. One that goes to the tutorial home screen and the other that will go to the screen every time the user opens the app after.

I have added the following code to the load page to determine if the tutroial is complete or not. The problem I am having is that my load page is doing nothing. Its not executing the code when it load. Here is the code:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class FrontPageViewController: UIViewController  {

   var isTutorialComplete = false;

   override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()
   // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib. 
       if (isTutorialComplete == false) {

       //Pushes to tutorial home page
       self.performSegueWithIdentifier("ToTutorialHome", sender: nil)
       }
       else 
       {  
        //pushes to tech home page
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("ToTechHome", sender: nil)
       }
   }

   override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
      super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
      // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
   }
}
```

[image]

[This is what the app is doing. I would like for it to not do this and move to a another view controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O1zrp.png)

Comment: Have you properly named your segue identifiers in the Storyboard?

Comment: Yes i copy and pasted them from the identifier box. I made the mistake of doing this before and it will throw and exception. It is not doing that. It is just not doing anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store the bool in **NSUserDefaults**.

First time when you load the NSUserDefaults value will be false when he finish the tutorial and click done you have to set it as true and it's done

> Do it like this

```
let settingdefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

var isTutorialComplete = settingdefaults.boolForKey("onboarding")

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


        if (isTutorialComplete){


            //pushes to tech home page
            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("ToTechHome", sender: nil)
        }
        else {

             //Pushes to tutorial home page
            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("ToTutorialHome", sender: nil)


        }


    }
```

> Once he finish the tutorial do like this

```
settingdefaults.setBool(true, forKey: "onboarding")
isTutorialComplete = settingdefaults.boolForKey("onboarding")
```

Comment: I understand this and plan on doing it. However, this is still not helping me switch the view controller when the screen load. At this point the load screen is doing nothing and just sitting there. My if else statement is not triggering the seque. Is there a function I can create to trigger this?

Comment: I created a function    func viewDidAppear(), placed code in there and it still seems to not move. I even tried calling the function in the viewDidLoad()

Comment: @AlexPriest What is the erro?

Comment: The error is that it will not move to the one of the two pages like I want it to. It just stays on the view controller that says Tech Tool and shows the spinning circle. I would like it to not stay on this page and move to one of the other view controllers

Comment: I attached another picture of what it is doing the the original post above with a description

Comment: @AlexPriest you there?

Comment: Yes we can, how do I contact you?